# Error setting sysctl parameters "net.ipv4.tcp_retries2" for a specific pod in the AKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am working on a requirement wherein we want to update a specific kernel parameter "net.ipv4.tcp_retries2" to "5" in the Kubernetes POD.

**We are using AKS cluster v1.21.7**

I tried using securityContext to set the above sysctl parameters but it failed

```
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: weather-forecast-api
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: RELEASE-NAME-weather-forecast-api
      securityContext:
        sysctls:
        - name: net.ipv4.tcp_retries2
          value: "5"
```

When I applied the above changes in the AKS, the pod failed to run and gave the error

> forbidden sysctl: "net.ipv4.tcp_retries2" not whitelisted

I know we can modify kernel-level settings at the Kubelet level on a bare-bone Kubernetes cluster but in my case, it is a managed cluster from Azure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an init container to set:

```
...
template:
  metadata:
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: weather-forecast-api
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
  spec:
    serviceAccountName: RELEASE-NAME-weather-forecast-api
    initContainers:
    - name: sysctl
      image: busybox
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      command: ["sh", "-c", "sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_retries2=3"]
    ...
```

Comment: This solution worked, but do you see any security concerns around using privileged:true in production?

Comment: The privilege setting above applied to the init container only. Your other containers can stay unprivileged.

Comment: thanks, mate. Just for understanding, could you explain how come initContainers and containers share the same kernel settings? also how come it does not affect other PODs kernel settings as well as the actual node's net.ipv4.tcp_retries2? any docs for reference? 
My understanding was that every container runs in isolation so how initConatiner changes reflects in the normal container?

Comment: That's a lot to cover... here's a [good article](https://www.cncf.io/blog/2019/06/24/demystifying-containers-part-i-kernel-space/) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Below steps resolved my issue: (This for setting netIpv4TcpFinTimeOut value at the pod level)

1. Created a config like below (name as linuxconfig.json)

```
{
  "allowedUnsafeSysctls":[
    "net.*"
  ],
  "sysctls": [
    "netIpv4TcpFinTimeOut": 20,
  ]
}
```

2. Added a nodepool with --kubelet-config

```
az aks nodepool add --name nodepoolname --cluster-name clustername --resource-group resourcegroupname –kubelet-config ./linuxconfig.json
```

3. Created the pod using below YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  securityContext:
    sysctls:
      - name: net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout
        value: "30"
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved by passing argument to kubelet.

1. Find the path of kubelet configuration file

```bash
systemctl status kubelet
```

It gives the path where kubelet configuration locates. In my case, it is **/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml**

2. Add allowedUnsafeSysctls option

Add allowedUnsafeSysctls option to the file.

```yaml
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
...
allowedUnsafeSysctls:
- "net.ipv4.tcp_retries2"
```

3. Restart Kubelet

```bash
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Done! But you should make sure that the pod should be scheduled on the node whose kubelet configuration is changed.